# Show and append a div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a HTML code where there are 3 divs - and in the `mainDiv2`, there is this another div that is hidden. When I click on the `mainDiv2`, I want to unhide the `hiddenDiv`(this I'm able to do it). As well as I want this `hiddenDiv` to be shown in `mainDiv1` as a child.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="mainDiv1">
This si a main div content
</div>
<div class="mainDiv2" onclick="showhiddenDiv()">
This is a sub div content
<div class="hiddenDiv" id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none">
Hello World
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function showhiddenDiv(){
    document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display="block";
}
```

please let me know how can I do this.

Here is a working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/8pj3uvfn/1/

Thanks

Comment: so hidden field div is  already set or after click it wil append

Comment: then why dont you use that div inside the first div

Comment: @SoubhagyaKumar hidden div is present

Comment: @SoubhagyaKumar this is a small example. This content is generated from sources

Comment: Why dont u use JQuery? it already has Show() & Hide() methods ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`appendChild`** like below

```js
function showhiddenDiv() {
  var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv');
  var mainDiv1 = document.getElementsByClassName('mainDiv1')[0];
  hiddenDiv.style.display = "block"
  mainDiv1.appendChild(hiddenDiv)
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv1" id="mainDiv1">
  This is a main div content
</div>
<div class="mainDiv2" onclick="showhiddenDiv()">
  This is a sub div content
  <div class="hiddenDiv" id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> As well as I want this hiddenDiv to be shown in mainDiv1 as a child.

You need to clone the `hiddenDiv` and put it in `mainDiv1`.

So modify your method as

```
function showhiddenDiv(){
    var hiddenNode = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv');
    hiddenNode.style.display="block";

    var copyHiddenNode = hiddenNode.cloneNode( true );
    copyHiddenNode.id += "_1"; //change the id so that ids are not duplicated
    document.getElementById("mainDiv1").appendChild( copyHiddenNode  );
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that he is aware to update his class of "mainDiv1" to an id instead to work this way

Answer (score 0):

You could use `appendChild`

```
function showhiddenDiv(){
  var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv');
  document.getElementsByClassName('mainDiv1')[0].appendChild(hiddenDiv);
  hiddenDiv.style.display="block";
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/820upz2h/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have set the `id` attributes of the divs properly,

```
function showhiddenDiv(){

    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv');   //Get the reference

    document.getElementById('mainDiv1').appendChild(hiddenDiv)   //Chenge the DOM order (you don't have to clone)

    hiddenDiv.style.display="block";   //Unhide    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="mainDiv1">
This si a main div content
</div>
<div class="mainDiv2" onclick="document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = 'block'">
This is a sub div content
<div class="hiddenDiv" id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none">
Hello World
</div>
</div>
```